# How to print @code section of a Razor page to the HTML view?

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm experimenting with Blazor for WebAssembly, and am looking for help with achieving something I found simple in basic JavaScript/HTML.

If I have a code section in an HTML page, in a script tag, I can easily show that section of code in my HTML view by setting the innerHTML of some element, say a div, to the innerHTML of that script tag. Like:

```
<div id="content" onload="fillDivWithCode()"></div>
<script id="code"> function foo() { return "bar"; } </script>
<script> 
  fillDivWithCode() {
    var div = document.getElementById("content");
    var codeScript = document.getElementById("code");
    div.innerHTML = codeScript.innerHTML;
    // now the entire contents of the "code" script will be shown in the DOM
  } 
</script>
```

However, say I want to do something similar in Blazor; how can I do it? For example, say my Razor page looks like

```
@page "/"
<div id="content"></div>

@code {
  private int currentCount = 0;

  private void IncrementCount()
  {
    currentCount++;
  }
}
```

I want to display inside the "content" div the entire code in the @code section -- can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: your "<script id="code"> function foo() { return "bar"; } </script>" resides on the client-side (browser), same place where "<div id="content" />" is. @code denotes component code. There is no programmatic way to get actual source code of the method (closest is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody I think)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, what you're describing is not possible, because the C# code is compiled. As close as you can get(that i'm aware of, but there may be another method) would be using GetMethodBody which can get you the IL code... but not the c# code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MethodBase_GetMethodBody

Answer (score 2):

Well,.. depending on how bad you want this, there are a few options that come to mind.

In a variety of ways you can have an automated task that processes your *.razor files, finds and extracts your @code blocks, and puts that content somewhere.

Maybe write it back into the page within a `<code>` block or save it to a resource or markdown file.

The trick is to get this happen automatically as part of build, commit, or deploy.

Here are some options:

1. Write a custom dotnet CLI command (can run manually as-needed or as a build task)
2. Do the same thing with a Roslyn task
3. Use a CI/CD build pipeline task (e.g. in Azure DevOps) to process files before compilation
4. Use git commit hooks and a custom npm tool

Sounds complicated?

Not really. I whipped up a dotnet CLI command that does exactly this:

https://github.com/mehalick/BlazorCodeExtractor

If you start with a simple **Index.razor** page:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

@code {
    private string _name = "Andy";
}
```

Just run `extract-blazor-code` from the command line (or as a build task) and you end up with an **Index.razor.md** file alongside your original file containing only your original @code block.

````
```
@code {
    private string _name = "Andy";
}
```
````

Now you can use show that file within any new or existing page.

Alternatively, and my first take, you can save the content directly into a `<code>` block in the original razor page instead of a separate markdown file. A version of this is a few commits back in the repo linked above.

Comment: It's doesn't do code-behind but I imagine that would be a bit easier.

Comment: Hey, thank you! This may be a dumb follow-up question, but how do I go about reading from the .md files in a Razor page, since they are not in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: You could update the CLI command to save into the wwwroot folder instead, admittedly I didn't experiment with actually using the file. You could also add a copy file built task although simply putting it there to begin with is probably easier.

Comment: Alternatively, and my first approach, add some markup into your razor file like you did in your question (<div id="content"></div>) and have the command inject the code content into that div instead of saving to a markdown file. 

This is doable but more difficult, you'd need to parse the file (perhaps with regex or an HTML parse library) and overwrite the div content. At that point you wouldn't have to do any extra work to display your code. Changing the original razor file has risk so be careful. The complexity of this approach and the risk are why I changed approaches a separate md file.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I'll update the command to write to the wwwroot folder. Thank you for your help Andy!